# Laravel 4 Model Relationship

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have 2 tables:
Buildings:

- id
- name
- address

Apartments:

- id
- building_id
- unit_number
- other_data

I also have 2 models:

Building Model

```
class Building extends Eloquent{


protected $table = 'buildings';


public function apartments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Apartment');
}
}
```

Apartment Model

```
class Apartment extends Eloquent{


protected $table = 'apartments';


public function building()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Building');
}

}
```

So now in my controller I am trying to retrieve all the apartments, and I want it joined with the Building Model so that I can retrieve the **name** of the building that each apartment is in.

```
Array('0' => 
array('id' => 1,
'building_id' => 1,
'unit_number'=>234,
'other_data'=>'other_stuff',
'name'=>'Building1'),
'1' => 
array('id' => 2,
'building_id' => 2,
'unit_number'=>567,
'other_data'=>'more_stuff',
'name'=>'Building4'))
```

I believe I can do this to get them independently, but how do I get them merged together?

```
$buildings = Building::all();
$apartments= Apartment::all();
```

This is what I've tried in the controller

```
$building = new Building();
$buildings = $building->all();
$apts = $building->find(1)->apartments();
dd($apts);
```

I've also tried many other variations of this in the controller with no success. Am I on the right track to retreiving the data the way I desire?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “get them merged together”?

Comment: I guess I am more used to retrieving data and it being returned in a simple array. I wanted the building_name to be right there in the array with the apartment data. But I see the results come back as an object. So as long as I can access them, which I can with lukasgeiter's answer, then I'm all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of querying the models separately you can just query one and *eager load* the relation so they all contain that data too:

```
$apartments = Apartment::with('building')->get();
foreach($apartments as $apartment){
    echo 'Building name: '.$apartment->building->name;
}
```

To get the apartments of a particular building:

```
$apartments = Building::find(1)->apartments;
```

(Note that I'm not calling the function `apartments()` but accessing the property `apartments`. Eloquent will then fetch the result of the relation for you)

Comment: Great. That worked perfect. Now I can read some more on eager loading to. Thanks